How can I fix the times listed in a dataframe on R?
I'm very new to R and cleaning a dataset that has times inconsistently entered, like this: 450pm, 10:00am, 245pm, 9am, 12:30pm.
I would like to make sure everything appears consistent and is either 3 or 4 digits, like this:
4:50pm, 10:00am, 2:45pm, 9:00am, 12:30pm.
How can I go about with doing this?
I played around with gsub and paste functions to try to add ':00' to numbers like '9am', but no luck. Would appreciate any help.

Maybe you can try sub like below
sub(
  "^(\\d+)(\\D+)$", "\\1:00\\2",
  sub("(\\d{1,2})(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", x)
)

which gives
"4:50pm"  "10:00am" "2:45pm"  "9:00am"  "12:30pm"

Data
x <- c("450pm", "10:00am", "245pm", "9am", "12:30pm")


library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x <- c("450pm", "10:00am", "245pm", "9am", "12:30pm")

times <- str_remove_all(x, "\\D")
period <- str_extract(str_to_lower(x), "(am|pm)$")

case_match(nchar(times),
           1 ~ str_c("0", times, "00"),
           2 ~ str_c(times, "00"),
           3 ~ str_c("0", times),
           .default = times) |>
  str_replace("\\d{2}", \(x) str_c(x, ":")) |>
  str_c(period)
# [1] "04:50pm" "10:00am" "02:45pm" "09:00am" "12:30pm"

dplyr isn't necessary here, but the use of case_match() cuts down on typing and I think is easier to read than a nested ifelse().
All these steps are doable in base R too, but I personally find stringr to be more readable.
Basically, this just extracts the numbers and zero pads them depending on their length. With them all the same length (should be four characters for HHMM) then we simply insert a colon and append the period.

Using parse_date_time to get the right Date class and format to extract the time. Based on the assumption that the time strings with : either have more than 6 characters or, if not, can be parsed directly.
library(lubridate)

format.Date(
  parse_date_time(
    ifelse(nchar(x) > 6, sub(":", "", x), paste0("0", x)), c("HMp", "Hp")),
  "%I:%M%P")
[1] "04:50pm" "10:00am" "02:45pm" "09:00am" "12:30pm" "09:01pm"

As a side effect you could also do time-based calculations with the parse_date_time result.
Data
x <- c("450pm", "10:00am", "245pm", "9am", "12:30pm", "9:01pm")

